# How to add dynamic tags to a column in Streamlit data_editor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tags, streamlit

I have a Streamlit data_editor `edited_df` created as below. I would like to add a dynamic tags column (st_keywords) to the data_editor for users to add/remove tags. Is this possible?

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
from streamlit_tags import st_tags

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
       {"command": "st.selectbox", "rating": 4, "is_widget": True},
       {"command": "st.balloons", "rating": 5, "is_widget": False},
       {"command": "st.time_input", "rating": 3, "is_widget": True},
   ]
)
edited_df = st.data_editor(df)

#How do I add this as a new column to edited_df?
st_keywords = st_tags(
    label='# Enter Keywords:',
    text='Press enter to add more',
    value=['Zero', 'One', 'Two'],
    suggestions=['five', 'six', 'seven', 
                 'eight', 'nine', 'three', 
                 'eleven', 'ten', 'four'],
    maxtags = 4,
    key='1')
```

Expected output will be data_editor with new column `st_tags` added:

[image]

Comment: Added expected output

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this isn't currently possible with `st.data_editor`. [Here](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/6857)'s the GitHub Issue where this feature request is being tracked.